# Any way of calculating MD5 or any other checksum of the final output text

Tags: tex-core

At the bottom of the final pdf, I would like to have the md5 of the entire text for control purposes.
Anybody came across any similar/same task?

Comment: You mean the md5 hash of the source (`.tex` file), not the PDF file itself, correct?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I mean checksum of the entire text, should it be pdf or any other output. This is to make sure the text has not been altered anyhow, as it is on several pages and printed on a paper. I cannot remember the other algorithms used to check the checksum/integrity of the printed document.

Comment: Adding the checksum to the text alters the checksum of the text which alters... You could use an external tool to calculate the MD5 and stamp the PDF, I'd look at pdftk if it offers such functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build-in command `\pdfmdfivesum`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\pdfmdfivesum file {\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Which prints the checksum:

[image]